# Making an interactive scatter plot with d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a scatter plot based on this example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887118.

What i want to do is add interactivity by allowing the user to choose the x and y dimensions, as well as the size of the circles based on one of the columns in the data file. When they choose something, the graph should automatically scale the axis.

How would i go about doing this? 
Here is my code so far: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZCdEBa79Y85Koz7MepXw?p=preview

Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

/*set the axis line color, dot stroke, font size, and font position*/
body {
  font: 15px sans-serif;
}

.name{
  position: relative;
  top: 90px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.title {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.dot {
  stroke: #000;
}

#filter {
  position: absolute;
}

#mark {
  padding-left: 150px;
  position: inherit;
}

#xAXs {
  position: relative;
  left: 290px;
  bottom: 30px;
}

#yAXs {
position: relative;
bottom: 30px;
left: 315px;

}

#label {
position: absolute;
top: 599px;
bottom: 125px;
left: 300px;
right: 0px;
}

#label2 {
position: absolute;
top: 599px;
bottom: 125px;
left: 430px;
right: 0px;
}

</style>

<body>


<script src="d3.min.js"></script>

<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);


var color = d3.scale.category10();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


d3.csv("iris.csv", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.petalLength = +d.petalLength;
    d.petalWidth = +d.petalWidth;
    d.sepalLength = +d.sepalLength;
    d.sepalWidth = +d.sepalWidth;
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.petalWidth; })).nice();
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.petalLength; })).nice();

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("x", width)
      .attr("y", -6)
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Petal Width (cm)");

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Petal Length (cm)")

 var circles = svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("r", 3.5)
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.petalWidth); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.petalLength); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.species); });


  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(color.domain())
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });


  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);


  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });



  d3.selectAll("[name=v]").on("change", function() {
      var selected = this.value;
      display = this.checked ? "inline" : "none";


  svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .filter(function(d) {return selected == d.species;})
      .attr("display", display);
      });



  d3.selectAll("[name=sepal]").on("change", function(d) {
     radius = this.value;


  svg.selectAll(".dot")
     console.log(radius);
     circles.attr("r", radius);
     });



  d3.select("[name=xAX]").on("change", function(){
    xAxy = this.value;
    console.log(xAxy)
  })

  d3.select("[name=yAX]").on("change", function(){
    yAxy = this.value;
    console.log(yAxy)
  })

});

</script>
<br><br>


  <div id="filter">
    <b>Species Filter:</b>
        <br>
    <input name='v' value="Iris-setosa" type="checkbox" checked>Iris-setosa
    </input>
        <br>
    <input name="v" value="Iris-versicolor" type="checkbox" checked >Iris-versicolor
    </input>
        <br>
    <input name="v" value="Iris-virginica" type="checkbox" checked >Iris-virginica
    </input>
  </div>


  <form id="mark">
    <b>Size of Mark:</b>
    <div><input type="radio" name="sepal" value='sepalWidth'>Sepal Width</div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="sepal" value="sepalLength">Sepal Length</div>
  </form>

<div id="label"><b>x-Axis:</b></div>
  <select name="xAX" id="xAXs">
        <option value ="petalWidth">petalWidth</option>
        <option value ="petalLength">petalLength</option>
        <option value ="sepalLength">sepalLength</option>
        <option value ="sepalWidth">sepalWidth</option>
  </select>

<div id="label2"><b>y-Axis:</b></div>
  <select name="yAX" id="yAXs">
        <option value ="petalLength">petalLength</option>
        <option value ="petalWidth">petalWidth</option>
        <option value ="sepalLength">sepalLength</option>
        <option value ="sepalWidth">sepalWidth</option>
  </select>  

  <br>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/MkZcXJPS7hrcWh3M0MZ1?p=preview

You were almost there, I just had to update a couple of your functions.  The following describes the highlights:

```
d3.selectAll("[name=sepal]").on("change", function(d) {
   radius = this.value;

   svg.selectAll(".dot")
   console.log(radius);
   circles.attr("r", function(d) { return d[radius]; });
});
```

You are setting `radius` to the column in the csv that you want to read the radius from, so now you just have to update the radius of your circles in the `svg`, which is basically done the same way as when you originally set them up.

```
d3.select("[name=xAX]").on("change", function(){
  xAxy = this.value;
  console.log(xAxy)
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[xAxy]; })).nice();

  svg.select(".x.axis").transition().call(xAxis);

  svg.selectAll(".dot").transition().attr("cx", function(d) { 
      return x(d[xAxy]);
  });
  svg.selectAll(".x.axis").selectAll("text.label").text(axisNames[xAxy] + " (cm)");
});

d3.select("[name=yAX]").on("change", function(){
  yAxy = this.value;
  console.log(yAxy)
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[yAxy]; })).nice();
  svg.select(".y.axis").transition().call(yAxis);
  svg.selectAll(".dot").transition().attr("cy", function(d) { 
      return y(d[yAxy]);
  });
  svg.selectAll(".y.axis").selectAll("text.label").text(axisNames[yAxy] + " (cm)");
});
```

The changes for the `x` and `y` axes are basically the same as each other, with just the axis being referenced getting changed.  Here I'm doing:

1. Updating the domain with the new range (based on the value of `xAxy` or `yAxy`)
2. Update the actual axis in the `svg` by setting up a transition and calling the `xAxis` or `yAxis` component again.
3. Update the `cx` or `cy` position of each `.dot`
4. Update the `text` on the axis by looking it up in a new array (`axisNames`) which gives a pretty print of the variable being graphed.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is asking a lot.  In general dynamic `d3` visualizations follow the enter, exit, and update pattern.  There's some [great](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) [tutorial's](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/) out there to get you started.

To fix your specific code, you divide into three parts.  First init the non-update-able portions of the plot:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("body").insert("svg",":first-child")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// keep reference to axises
var xg = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");
xg
  .append("text")
  .attr("class", "label")
  .attr("x", width)
  .attr("y", -6)
  .style("text-anchor", "end");

var yg = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis");
yg
  .append("text")
  .attr("class", "label")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end");

// legend is always static
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
    .data(color.domain())
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

legend.append("rect")
    .attr("x", width - 18)
    .attr("width", 18)
    .attr("height", 18)
    .style("fill", color);

legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", width - 24)
    .attr("y", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

Then wrap the update-able portion in a function:

```
function update(){

  // get user selections
  var xVar = d3.select('#xAXs').node().value,
    yVar = d3.select('#yAXs').node().value;

  var checks = {};
  d3.selectAll('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
    checks[this.value] = this.checked;
  });

  var radAttr = d3.select('input[type=radio]:checked').node().value;

  // filter data based on user selections
  var data = baseData.filter(function(d,i){
    d.x = d[xVar]; // create/modify a x,y so that d3 will know it's an update
    d.y = d[yVar];
    return checks[d.species];
  });

  // set domains
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.x; })).nice();
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.y; })).nice();

  xg.call(xAxis);
  yg.call(yAxis);

  xg.select("text").text(xVar);
  yg.select("text").text(yVar);

  // on enter
  var circles = svg.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(data);

  circles.enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot");

  circles.exit().remove();

  // on update
  circles.attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.species); })
    .attr("r", function(d){ return d[radAttr]; });
}
```

Finally trigger update on user actions:

```
d3.selectAll('select').on('change',function(){
  update();
});

d3.selectAll('input').on('click', function(){
  update();
})
```

Here's an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/GchLefHNjHOb6BQ9AbLN?p=preview) putting this together.